# When most generally are maps $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ conformal?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, conformal-geometry, jacobian

I'm interested in continuous conformal maps $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ that are ONLY angle preserving (not necessarily orientation preserving). I would like to write down a generic system of PDEs such that ALL conformal maps must obey this PDE (or maybe some other suitable functional equation).

It's a well known fact that all holomorphic functions are conformal and a holomorphic function can basically be characterized as a map $D: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ with two components $u(x,y),v(x,y)$ such that the [cauchy riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations) hold.

$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{ \partial v}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = - \frac{ \partial v}{\partial x} $$

But not ALL conformal maps are holomorphic... namely if we move that minus sign to the upper equation we would get an "anti holomorphic" cauchy riemann equation. (See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1129353/cauchy-riemann-eq-for-anti-holomorphic-function) for an explanation).

So there are at least two different systems of two PDEs whose general solutions result in conformal maps.

Now I haven't seen any result to suggest that harmonic functions are conformal but they certainly seem [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4826/harmonic-function-composed-with-conformal-map-is-harmonic-in-mathbbrn) and moreover both holomorphic and antiholomorphic functions are harmonic.

So that leads us to the question, can we some characterize ALL conformal maps by a single system of PDEs?

### An attempt at an approach:

We try to do this the ugly way... Suppose we have two parametrized curves $\gamma_1 = (\gamma_{1,x}(t), \gamma_{1,y}(t))$ and $\gamma_2 = (\gamma_{2,x}(t), \gamma_{2,y}(t))$

Now suppose these intersect at $t = t_0$ we can then discuss the angle between the curves as

$$ \theta_{\text{original}} = \left| \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{\frac{d\gamma_{2,y}}{dt}}{ \frac{d\gamma_{2,x}}{dt} } \right) -  \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{\frac{d\gamma_{1,y}}{dt}}{ \frac{d\gamma_{1,x}}{dt} } \right) \right|  @ t = t_0  $$

Now we consider some arbitrary map on $\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ consisting of two components $u(x,y), v(x,y)$ where the $u$ is our x coordinate and $v$ is our y coordinate.

So we talk about the angle between the two curves after applying this map and set the two things equal to each other. So that angle is given as:

$$ \theta_{\text{new}} = \left| \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{\frac{d v\left( \gamma_{2,x}, \gamma_{2,y} \right) }{dt}}{ \frac{d u\left( \gamma_{2,x}, \gamma_{2,y} \right)}{dt} } \right) -  \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{\frac{d v\left( \gamma_{1,x}, \gamma_{1,y} \right)}{dt}}{ \frac{d u\left( \gamma_{1,x}, \gamma_{1,y} \right) }{dt} } \right) \right|  @ t = t_0  $$

which we can expand via the chain rule to find

$$  \left| \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{\frac{\partial v }{\partial x } \frac{d \gamma_{2,x}}{dt} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \frac{d  \gamma_{2,y}} {dt} }{ \frac{\partial u }{\partial x } \frac{d \gamma_{2,x}}{dt} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{ d\gamma_{2,y}}{dt}} \right) -  \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{\frac{\partial v }{\partial x } \frac{d \gamma_{1,x}}{dt} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \frac{d  \gamma_{1,y}} {dt} }{ \frac{\partial u }{\partial x } \frac{d \gamma_{1,x}}{dt} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{ d\gamma_{1,y}}{dt}} \right) \right|. $$

So a characterization of all conformal curves maps is the following:

$$  \left| \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{\frac{\partial v }{\partial x } \frac{d \gamma_{2,x}}{dt} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \frac{d  \gamma_{2,y}} {dt} }{ \frac{\partial u }{\partial x } \frac{d \gamma_{2,x}}{dt} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{ d\gamma_{2,y}}{dt}} \right) -  \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{\frac{\partial v }{\partial x } \frac{d \gamma_{1,x}}{dt} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \frac{d  \gamma_{1,y}} {dt} }{ \frac{\partial u }{\partial x } \frac{d \gamma_{1,x}}{dt} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{ d\gamma_{1,y}}{dt}} \right) \right| = \left| \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{\frac{d\gamma_{2,y}}{dt}}{ \frac{d\gamma_{2,x}}{dt} } \right) -  \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{\frac{d\gamma_{1,y}}{dt}}{ \frac{d\gamma_{1,x}}{dt} } \right) \right| $$

Of course this definition sucks because of the dependence on the arbitrary $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ curves, which we would like to remove somehow. It's not even obvious if $u,v$ is holomorphic (meaning obyeing cauchy riemann) that this equation holds true (perhaps some trig identity is required there).

Comment: Just checking: 1. Are you allowing critical points (isolated points where a mapping is not conformal)? 2. Are mappings defined on regions, or is the interest only in "entire" functions? <> Separately, the complex conjugate of an "antiholomorphic" map is holomorphic, which should give a good characterization regardless of the answers to 1. and 2.

Comment: the interest is only in entire functions, I'm not opposed to critical points (1). if that makes characterizing them in general easier

Comment: Thanks; is the question, then, to write down a single (system of) PDE whose solutions are precisely holomorphic and conjugate-holomorphic functions, or is there also the question of whether there are other conformal maps of the plane (there aren't)?

Comment: The question is the latter as well, I assumed there would be conformal maps that aren’t Holomorphic or antiholomorphic but perhaps that assumption is mistaken?

Comment: it becomes a system,  $$  u_x^2 + u_y^2 = v_x^2 + v_y^2 $$  $$ u_x v_x + u_y v_y = 0$$

Comment: How did u derive that system from the definition of conformality? when I tried to take a determinant of the jacobian I seemed to have messed it up somewhere so that only the second equation came out naturally but not the first. I've undeleted my rightfully downvoted answer showing my approach.

Comment: I wrote  $J^T J = \lambda I  $  Certainly possible that the usual falls out if you assume $C^2$ and restrict to points where not too many quantities are zero.

Comment: do u wanna write that as an answer? Your equations hold true even if $\lambda$ is not constant

Comment: @WillJagy I typed it up as an answer but I think i found a typo in your comment (I guess it depends on how one defines the jacobian), i defined my jacobian as same function along each row, same derivative along each column.

Comment: Oh wait I see a way to equate our solutions if we let $JJ^T = \lambda I_2$ vs $J^T J$  then your equation plops out, I think our systems must be equivalent then since orthogonal matrices by definition have both $JJ^T$ and $J^TJ$ equal to scalar times identity. Still kind of weird though...

Comment: If  $AB  = t I$  we know $B$ and $A$  are nonsingular, also $BA$  is nonsingular. Next, $BABA = B(AB)A = tBA.$ There is an $(BA)^{-1},$   so $BABA (BA)^{-1}  = t BA (BA)^{-1} = tI.$   And $BA = tI$

Answer (score 1):

@Will Jagy's  approach was the following we can write down conformality as meaning the jacobian matrix is a scalar times orthogonal matrix i.e.

$$ J^T J = \lambda(x,y) I_2 $$

We now expand this

$$  \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} \\ \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}  \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}  \end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda(x,y) & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda(x,y) \end{bmatrix} $$

From here we conclude that that by equating the two lambda components:

$$ \left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} \right)^2 = \left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \right)^2  $$

And that

$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = 0$$

This gives us our system of two PDES for conformality